# return to the main menu from any UIViewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm wondering if there is any way to return from `UIViewController` like 3-4 step backward, I've a main screen which will navigate to other `UIViewController` via `presentModalViewController`, on the next view, it will have a `UINavigationBar` which will navigate to a 4-5 level deeps. i wanna to put a button that let the user go back to the home directly without returning for all the view he enter.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your root level view controller register as an observer of a notification, such as "POP_TO_ROOT".  When it receives this notification, call a method to dismiss your modal view controller (or whatever is first on the stack).

In your viewcontroller stack, any of the views 4 or 5 levels in can just post a notification "POP_TO_ROOT".

**EDIT: add code**

In your main "screen" before you call presentModalViewController, do this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(handlePopToRoot) 
                                                 name:@"POP_TO_ROOT"
                                               object:nil];
```

and add this method:

```
 - (void) handlePopToRoot {
     [[NotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                   name:@"POP_TO_ROOT" 
                                                 object:nil];
     [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; 
 }
```

Then, down deep in your viewcontroller hierarchy, when you want to pop all the way out,
 you just need to post a notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"POP_TO_ROOT" object:nil];
```

Comment: i didn't get your solution, can you post some code to make it clear to me ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, and thank you for the code, between, i don't use navigation controller, i've just use [self presentModelViewController:Viewname animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Save your root View Controller in some property and call: 
`- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: My main menu is not a root controller, so i can't use the self.navigationController

Comment: Updated answer with new detail.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are presenting a navigation controller (with a root view controller attached to it) from your "main view controller" modally, and you want to be able to get back to your "main view controller".

Because you will always have pointer to your navigation controller, you should be able to call 
`dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` from any of your view controllers and it will take you right back to the main view controller.

```
    [[self.navigationController parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: this will take me back one view, i wanna let it take me back for example 4 view.